# Incorrect range for mosaic returned by calculate statistics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mosaic, animation, timeslider

Hoping someone can catch an error here-- I'm working towards a time anaimation of rasters contained in a mosaic. Most of the animation is blank however because most of the rasters contained are outside of the range of values given by calculate statistics. I have double-checked that the rasters really do have values outside of the range given, which should go inbetween 3100 - 6663 (see excel sheets). Instead I get a much smaller range--e.g. 3164 - 3269. One excel sheet highlights 20 consecutive rasters which show this smaller range as their max/mins. One thing I considered is the possibly that having Maximum Number of Items Downloadeable per Request = 20 (as seen in the mosaic properties) limits the number of rasters that are used in calculate statistics, however if I literally change this from 20 to 10,000 in the same window, I get the same smaller range. Any ideas?

[image: Stats]

[image: Stats2]

[image: RasterInfo]

[image: ImageInfo]

[image: ImageInfo2]